# Copy Google sheet to a new sheet using cell value from 3rd sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been looking through the forums trying to search for the right way to do this but I can't seem to get it right. This is my first time using Google Apps Script so I'm learning as I'm going.

This is what I'm trying to do.

1) I want to duplicate all the contents of an old sheet into a new sheet. The script will determine the existing sheet name by referring to the cell b17 from 'Statistics' sheet, and will duplicate the old sheet, including values formats, references and formulas. The duplicated sheet will be named from cell c17 of the 'Statistics' sheet.

2) If possible I would also like to make the old sheet remove all the references and just keep the values and formats after the new sheet has been created. Similar to the copy all and ctrl-shift-v, except automating it in one fell swoop.

This is the code i currently have, not sure if it is correct

```
  function newSheetLast() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Statistics").activate();
  var oldSheetName = ss.getRange('b17').getDisplayValue();
  var newSheetName = ss.getRange('c17').getDisplayValue();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(oldSheetName).activate();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().duplicateActiveSheet(newSheetName);
};
```

I am getting stuck when trying to do 1. I tried the copyTo and can get the sheet to copy, but loose all the formatting and formulas when i copy over to the new sheet.

I am not sure how to even attempt 2

Answer (score 0):

You variable naming and the way duplicating sheets works is a bit confusing.
You should really be able to duplicate a Sheet Object directly or at least be able to try and supply the name of the sheet you are trying to duplicate but no, it  is on a Spreadsheet level and only works on the active sheet...

Duplicating a sheet carries formulae and formatting.
Overwriting with static values can be done with `setValues(getValues)`.

```
function newSheetLast() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var settings = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var oldSheetName = settings.getRange('B17').getDisplayValue();
  var oldSheet = ss.getSheetByName(oldSheetName);
  var newSheetName = settings.getRange('C17').getDisplayValue();
  ss
      .getSheetByName(oldSheetName)
      .activate()
      .getParent()
      .duplicateActiveSheet()
      .setName(newSheetName);

  oldSheet.getDataRange().setValues(oldSheet.getDataRange().getValues());
};
```